# VSCode extension contribute dropdown menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode extension that turns selected text into styled comments, and is activated using a specific key-binding. I've defined a configuration which is an array of styles configurations:

```
"configuration": {
        "title": "MyExtension",
        "properties": {
            "my-extension.commentsConfigs": {
                "type": "array",
                "description": "Comments configurations",
                "default": [
                    {
                        "name": "Section header",
                        "fillChar": "*",
                        "alignment": "left",
                        "lineLength": 80
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is that when a user calls my key-binding with text selected, a dropdown menu of all comments configs will appear (like when choosing a task). Couldn't figure out what [contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points) I need to use.

Comment: look for the `QuickPick` in the VSC API page

Answer (score 0):

As `rioV8` commented, the solution is to use the `QuickPick` VSCode's API rather than contribute anything.